# what are the files needs to be edit to add a new user to ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to write a C program to add a new user to my Ubuntu 14.04.
I edited

1) /etc/passwd

```
sachin:x:65535:1:sachin:/home/sachin:/bin/bash
```

2) /etc/shadow

```
sachin:$6$VwBWgroA$t4KXLWIf81sWtiA1/a.fRLrXaOAflGtMo73hGvCzp/M6S8oizZ4iqk.vYbkblXZj2hgGXJxlJ.M2hghGO.a650:16294::::::
```

3) .profile

```
stty istrip
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/share/bin:.
export PATH
```

After this when I run - ls -l /home/

```
drwxr-xr-x 43 mrcr mrcr 4096 Aug 12 10:27 mrcr
d-w------t  2 sachin    sachin    4096 Aug 12 11:11 sachin
```

Where "sachin" is created by my rpogram, "mrcr" is created normally. I changed the permissions like a normal user home

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 sachin    sachin    4096 Aug 12 11:11 sachin
```

I copied all files from "mrcr" home directory to "sachin" home directory(.bashrc, Desktop ..etc)

Now in login screen "sachin" is there to login. but even if I enter correct password I can't login into it. It will load again the same login screen. given below is my entire code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct passwd *userlist;
    int count, usernumber, len1;
    FILE *tmp, *stmp, *mailer, *profile;
    char *commentfield, *username, *userdir, *home;
    char *mailcomment, *mailmail, reply;

    commentfield = (char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    username = (char *)malloc(8*sizeof(char));
    userdir = (char *)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    home = (char *)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    mailcomment = (char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    mailmail = (char *)malloc(512*sizeof(char));

    if (argc!=4)
    {
        printf("usage : %s [dirname- no slashes] [logname] [comment - in quotes]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (strlen(argv[2]) < 5) || (strlen(argv[2]) > 8) )
    {
        printf("pls enter logname between 5-8 \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

    setpwent();

    count = 0;

    while((userlist = getpwent()) != NULL)
    {
        if(count < userlist->pw_uid)
        {
            count = userlist->pw_uid ; 
            usernumber = count + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("usernumber : %d\n", usernumber);

    endpwent();

    sprintf(commentfield,"%s", argv[3]);
    sprintf(username, "%s", argv[2]);
    sprintf(userdir, "%s", argv[1]);
    sprintf(home, "/%s/%s", argv[1], argv[2]);



    printf("\n Check this out here: \n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n username      :\t %s", username);
    printf("\n Home Directory:\t %s", home);
    printf("\n comment       :\t %s", commentfield);
    printf("\n______________________________________________\n\n");

    printf("all of this ok? n/y: ");
    scanf("%c", &reply);

    if(reply != 'y')
    {
        printf("\n exiting....u entered not y");
        exit(1);
    } 

    tmp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "a");
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\npermission denied\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(tmp, "%s:x:%d:1:%s:%s:/bin/bash\n", username, usernumber, commentfield, home);
    fclose(tmp);



    stmp = fopen("/etc/shadow", "a");
    if (stmp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\npermission denied\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stmp, "%s:*LK*:::::::\n", username);
    fclose(stmp);

    mkdir(home, 0755);
    chdir(home);


    profile = fopen(".profile", "a");
    fprintf(profile, "stty istrip\n");
    fprintf(profile, "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/share/bin:.\n");
    fprintf(profile, "export PATH\n");
    fprintf(profile, "\n\n");
    fclose(profile);

    chown(home, usernumber, 1);
    chown(".profile", usernumber, 1);
    chmod(".profile", 0644);


    printf("\n\nALL done!!!!!!!\n Now set the password: ");
    execl("/usr/bin/passwd", "passwd", username, NULL);
    printf("\n\n SUCCESS PASSWORD IS SET.....BYE!!!\n\n");

}
```

QUESTIONS:

what are the files needs to be edit?

How can i run the program without to be a root?

what changes i needs to put in my code?

Comment: Why are you recreating `useradd` badly?

Comment: This is just a bad idea through and through.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably not answer your question directly, but I think is important - because Unix commands usually tend to have really well tested and defined functions to do pretty much everything needed to create, edit, and remove users, I think you should not try to recreate one by yourself.  Among other things that can be wrong, I don't think you can edit `/etc/shadow` successfully without using the utilities included in the OS.  The best advice I can give you (some may disagree, but seems better to me IMHO) is to call the `useradd` command with the needed arguments from your `C` code, instead of trying to create the wheel again.

Comment: does "useradd" is the function ubuntu calls when we try to manually add a new user? then how can i get entire cource code for my ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: According to the `libuser` package's information, the source code should be under `https://fedorahosted.org/libuser/`.  But I'm not 100% sure that this is the correct package.  Other distros seem to use the `shadow*` package.

Comment: i dont unserstand.. am using ubuntu 14.04. and can't i get a file named "source code ubuntu 14.04" something like this? what is libuser?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a fun project!

I'm running Arch so I can't give you the exact answer, but what I did to check it out is create a file to mark a time, add a user and then find all the files modified since the start file was created:

```
$ touch start
$ useradd -m temp
$ find / -cnewer start -print
```

You can zone in on the `find` (i.e. only search `/etc` or folders likely to have changes), but in the end it looks like you are touching all the main folders being changed except `/etc/gshadow` and `/etc/group`.

Also reading the man page of `useradd` it looks like you might have to look at `/etc/subgid` and `/etc/subuid` as they deal with group and user IDs.

As for your question of running your code without sudo you could look into setting the [SUID or GUID bits](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/028.html). Which will let you run the code as a root while being a normal.  Keep in mind **you will be running something as root while being a normal user**, which is always something to understand before doing.